# Combining plots and save them in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have some plots in R and I can't plot them at the same time (due to the margin of the screen). I have 36 plots and im using the `par(mfrow=c(6,6))` command, but the maximum amount of items I have plotted is 25 `par(mfrow=c(5,5))`.

Is there any way to save this plots instead of plotting them as the screen size doesn't allow me to plot all of them? (**1**)

I have not manage the way to do it with **plot** function. I think it can be done with **ggplot2** library but im plotting a specific histogram and I cant plot it using **geom_histogram**. Assume **cc** is a **nxn correlation matrix** (I have 36 of them). Is there a way to do it with ggplot2? (**2**)

```
L<-length(cc[upper.tri(cc)])
h <- hist(cc[upper.tri(cc)])
h$counts<- h$counts/sum(h$counts)
plot(h,ylab="Probability",xlab="Pearson Correlation",main = paste("Cluster nº ",as.character(i),", ",as.character(L)," genes",sep=""))
```

[image]

Thank u in advance.

Comment: try typing `?png` into your console. Or `pdf` if you prefer.

Comment: To better explain: call the `png` function specifying height, width, file etc. Run your plotting function. Then, call `dev.off()`. See examples in `?png`

Comment: Thank u! I tick it as solved